# How to append strings to a vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I am new to R. I am trying to append values from a data frame like this
here is the data frame tu :

```
         t     u
1     What   LOL
2 Whatever   ALL
3    Works   OLO
4     What  POLO
5 Whatever CHOLO
6 Whatever  LOLO
7    Works     C
8 Whatever     D
```

I want to print the values of u for which t is "Whatever"

```
a <- vector()
for(i in 1:8) {
if(tu$t[i] == 'Whatever') {
  a<-c(a,tu$u[i])
}}
```

When the execution is complete I am getting the value of `print(a)` as an integer type Vector instead of a vector of a set of strings. "ALL CHOLO LOLO D"

The output is `int [1:4] 1 3 6 4` Can anybody explain what is happening?
PS: Ignore the values of u :P

Comment: please include a sample of your data

Comment: I mentioned the data frame in the question

Comment: Yes you did, but that does not tell us about the class of your columns. What does `sapply(tu, class)` return?

Comment: it returns        `t        u 
"factor" "factor"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert your columns to characters

```
tu$t <- as.character(tu$t)
tu$u <- as.character(tu$u)
```

And then rerun the code

Comment: would you be kind enough to explain me why does this work in your answer?